# Wordpress issue - siteurl and home option is being changed every time I log into the admin

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I hope you can help me.
For some unknown reason, every time I log into the admin and update the site, afterwards the "siteurl" and "home" paths are always changed to a previously used "testsubdomain". I already hired a developer who gave up telling me that he isn't a Wordpress specialist and can't see where the issue is.

What I have done until now, I just went into the phpmyadmin every time I noticed that it happened again, and changed the entries back to its correct path manually. This has become a real pain because every time this happens, the contact form entries aren't forwarded to the client either, and he is losing potential business.

Can anyone help and point me into a direction of how to fix this?
The site is http://www.chinatownband.com.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check if you have any plugins which are causing this. Disable all plugins and then check of the issue still exists. If not enable plugins one at a time and see which plugin is causing this issue. Also check if you have any code in your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: There are too many possible answers to this question for anyone here to diagnose it for you. Have you considered hiring another developer?

Comment: @NathanDawson: this is not that difficult; is this an advertisement for yourself for the job? :)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the URLs are hardcoded in either wp-config.php or the active theme functions.php file. Those are locations that read the URL settings for WordPress and can be used to fix or hardcode the URLs because they will override the URL settings in the database (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL ).

You're looking for

```
define('WP_HOME','http://testsubdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://testsubdomain.com');
```

If you find those, delete them and then change to `http://www.chinatownband.com` in the database with phpmyadmin as you have been doing.

If those settings are not in wp-config.php or the active theme functions.php file, download the whole theme and use a text editor to search the folder for those `define` lines.

And look in the root web directory for any non-core WordPress files and folders and check them, too.

In the end, you may also need to use https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB to safely find/replace URLs in the database. The URLs you are changing are only the 2 settings URLs and don't retroactively change any URLs in page/post content that are links to media, other pages, etc.

Comment: Thank you for all your tips, but I couldn't figure it out myself, so I ended up hiring a Wordpress specialist, and he actually solved the issue. I have yet to ask what the issue was, I'll probably post it here shortly.